# Changing html button Class from Data in Model (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this HTML button

```
<li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" style="text-decoration:none;"></button></li>
```

Where "Item" is an Item in Model

```
@foreach (var Item in Model)
```

I am looking for one field in item "Item" that is `Item.ID`

I want to change the button class from

```
class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"
```

To this

```
class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-heart"
```

If the value is of ID is equal to 1

But I don't want to create an additional button using `IF/ELSE` statement such as

```
@if (Item.ID == 0)
  {
 <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" onclick="Run(@Item.ID)"></button></li>                    
  }
  else
  {
 <li><button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-heart" onclick="Run(@Item.ID)"></button></li>
 }
```

Is there a better way to achieve this so I only change the CLASS

Cheers

Comment: You wrote same thing twice, _"from `class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"` to `class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"`"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ternary operator` here.

```
class="btn-link glyphicon @(Item.ID == 0 ? "glyphicon-heart-empty" : "glyphicon-heart")"
```

Comment: Cheers for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You cant also try this:

```
@{string glyphicon = string.empty}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    { glyphicon = item.Id == 0 ? "btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"
                               : "btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart";
    }

    <li>
        <button class="btn-link glyphicon @glyphicon" onclick="Run(@item.ID)"></button>
    </li> 
}
```